# How to get the ethereum address on phantom wallet?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, solana-web3js, wallet-connect

I am trying to get the ethereum address on phantom wallet but I can't find a way to do it, Here in my code I check first if phantom wallet is installed then get the solana addess but i need also to get the ethereum address.

```
const handlePhantom = async () => {
    if (window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom) {
      try {
        await window.solana.connect();

        const publicKey = window.solana.publicKey.toString();
        const ethAddress = `0x${publicKey}`;
        console.log(ethAddress);
        if (!_.isNil(publicKey)) {
          setUserInfo({
            ...userInfo,
            walletAddress: publicKey.toLowerCase(),
          });
          setconnectButton(true);
          setOpenConfirmChanges(true);
        } else {
          setAlert((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            type: 'error',
            isShow: true,
            content: 'No wallet account found!',
          }));
          setUserInfo({
            ...userInfo,
            walletAddress: '',
          });
          setconnectButton(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setAlert((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          type: 'error',
          isShow: true,
          content: 'Please select your account wallet.',
        }));
        // Handle error connecting to the wallet
      }
    } else {
      setAlert((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        type: 'error',
        isShow: true,
        content: 'Please install Phantom Wallet to your browser.',
      }));

      // Handle case where Phantom wallet is not installed or detected
    }
  };
```